# Match date pattern that precedes SED range match and include the matching range in output

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

Having issues with trying to set variable (example: `str_pattern`) with multiple values and then using those in `sed` command to match range in reverse to previous blank line or back to `ExecuteThread`.

- Example script snippet

  ```bash
  str_pattern="String1
  String2"

  tac $file | sed -n '/'"$str_pattern"'/,/^$/p' | tac
  ```
- Example input File

```
2023-01-01 01:00:00
    --blank line --
     ExecuteThread: #100 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)  
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.something
     
     ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)  
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line1   
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line2  
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodA(StackTraceExample.java:9)
      
     --blank line --
2023-01-01 02:00:00
    ExecuteThread: #100 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)  
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.something

     ExecuteThread: #102 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)  
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line1   
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line2  
     at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodA(StackTraceExample.java:9)
      
     --blank line --
```

- Desired Output

```
2023-01-01 01:00:00
    ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
         at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line1   
         at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line2  
2023-01-01 02:00:00    
    ExecuteThread: #102 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
         at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line1   
         at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line2
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain why you have to "match range in reverse...", etc., (with two `tac` calls), and why matching in the normal (forward) direction won't work? Thx.

Comment: Your code tries to get all lines from the start of each stack trace to the last line that mentions one of the two strings, but you also remove at least one line from the _start_ of the trace according to the output. Could you possibly update the expected output with what you want or make this clearer in the text? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl for this because it has an option (`-00`) for handling input in paragraphs (separated by one-or-more blank lines) and good multi-line string handling.

Perl's `-n` option makes it work like `sed -n` (read and process the input without automatically printing each input line)....and `sed -p` makes it work like `sed` (read, process and auto-print the input)

```
$ perl -00 -n -e '
    if (/String1|String2/) {
      s/^.*StackTraceExample.*$//mg;
      s/\n\n/\n/g;
      print;
    }' input.txt 
 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line1
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line2

 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line1
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line2
```

In English:

If the current paragraph contains String1 or String 2, then delete all lines containing StackTraceExample (if any), then remove any excess newlines that might remain after deleting the StackTraceExample lines, then print the modified paragraph.

If you need to pass String1, String2, ... StringN to perl from a sh or bash script, one way is to pass them via exported variables in the environment:

```
#!/bin/sh

str_pattern="String1|String2"
excl_pattern="StackTraceExample"
export str_pattern excl_pattern

perl -00 -n -e '
  if (/$ENV{str_pattern}/) {
    s/^.*(?:$ENV{excl_pattern}).*$//mg;
    s/\n\n/\n/g;
    print
  }' input.txt 
 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line1
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line2

 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line1
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line2
```

The values in `str_pattern` and `excl_pattern` will be interpreted as perl regular expressions, NOT fixed strings, so escape any special characters you want to be treated as literals.

`%ENV` is a hash (associative array) in perl which provides access to environment variables.

Note: unfortunately, bash arrays can't be usefully exported (`export` doesn't return an error code, but they're not available in the environment of external programs - e.g. try running `export foo=(1 2 3); declare -p foo ; env | grep ^foo=` in bash, and `foo` will appear in `declare`'s output, but not in `env`'s output), so the variables have to be scalar strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

You can use `fff`, Raku's version of sed's ["Flip-Flop" operator](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_fff).

Below starts capture on a line starting with `\s* ExecuteThread`, and ends capture on a `[^^ $$]` blank line (`*.chars == 0` also works). The desired strings "String1" and "String2" are tested for (literally):

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if m/   [^^ \s* ExecuteThread ] / fff / [^^ $$ ] / { .put if \
                m/ | [^^ \s* ExecuteThread ] 
                   | String1 
                   | String2 
                   | [^^ $$ ] / };'  file
```

Cleaning up a bit, the desired strings `String1` and `String2` can be abstracted out into a `regex` class variable named `desired`:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my regex desired { String1 | String2 };  \
             if m/   [^^ \s* ExecuteThread ] / fff / [^^ $$ ] / { .put if \
                m/ | [^^ \s* ExecuteThread ] 
                   | <desired>
                   | [^^ $$ ] / };'  file
```

Furthermore, same abstraction trick can make the code a little DRY-er by also declaring `start` and `stop` regex class variables. So we come to this version:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my regex start   { ^^ \s* ExecuteThread };  \
             my regex stop    { ^^ $$ };                 \
             my regex desired { String1  |  String2  };  \
             if (m/ <start> / fff / <stop> /) { 
                .put if m/ <start> | <desired> | <stop> / };'  file
```

Note, after the initial `fff` grouping/selection, a simpler approach might be ***removing*** unwanted lines from the output, for example, by the final clause `{.put unless m/StackTraceExample/}`.

Sample Input:

```
--blank line --

 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)  
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line1   
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line2  
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodA(StackTraceExample.java:9)

 --blank line --

 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodB(StackTraceExample.java:13)  
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line1   
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line2  
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.StackTraceExample.methodA(StackTraceExample.java:9)

 --blank line --
```

Sample Output (all code examples above):

```
 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line1   
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String1.line2  

 ExecuteThread: #101 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line1   
 at com.stackify.stacktrace.String2.line2
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org